# WPMU schedule doesn't execute actions

Tags: php, multisite, wp-cron

Here's a simple event that is correctly scheduled to be executed `daily`. Unfortuantely, it doesn't execute `delete_old_users()` function daily. It is supposed to delete users older than a certain date.

```
function delete_old_users() {
    $old_users = get_site_option( 'old_users' );

    foreach ( $old_users as $user_id => $expiration_time ) {
        if ( $expiration_time <= gmmktime() ) {
            wpmu_delete_user( $user_id );
        }
    }
    return;
}
add_action( 'delete_old_users_daily', 'delete_old_users' );


function setup_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_old_users_daily' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'delete_old_users_daily');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'setup_schedule' );
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? When I manually do `do_action( 'delete_old_users_daily' )` it works. I'm out of ideas. It just doesn't execute my action and I have no idea how to debug that.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Have you tried a hook besides `wp`? Also, Where/how is the `old_users` site option set? Why not just use the registration date for the user (Not directly related to the question, I know. Just curious.)?

Comment: @s_ha_dum `get_blogs_of_user()` didn't return "registered date" so I created my own option. `old_users` is an `array(ID => timestamp_when_registered)`. I now see that `get_blog_details()` returns registered date so I'll switch to that. I'll log debug information and check back tomorrow but I think that there is no mistake here. And this server supports CRON and all similar stuff.

Comment: @s_ha_dum debug showed: `[24-Aug-2013 16:28:29] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wpmu_delete_user() in /home/example/ftp/example.com/wp-content/plugins/expiration/expiration.php on line 96` - I'm wondering why could this function be missing at this point?

Comment: Changing hook name to the one without underscores didn't help as one user suggested.

Comment: That is a good question and I am afraid I don't know the answer. It appears that parts of wpmu are not loaded. I don't know why. Sorry.

Comment: A WP developer helped me resolve this. wp-cron.php executes with front-end context and this function doesn't exist there. It needs to be included manually.

Comment: I thought about doing that but it is easy to get a cascade of errors and I was not in a position to test things. Please post your working code in the answer box.